# How to Use an Internal Style Sheet in The Page Where The TinyMCE Editor Is Embedded?

Tags: html, css, tinymce

Want to modify the tinymce editor through embedded style within the html. Do not wanna use an separat .css file. Have no access to the configuration of the editor, no tinmce.init(). Weirdly, cannot access the tinymce editor with style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<style>
    body#tinymce.mce-content-body {
        background-color:red !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea'
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `content_style` option for the TinyMCE configuration?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

You could also just pass an entire HTML document into TinyMCE and place CSS in the head of the document.

Comment: thanks, but I've no access to the configuration to the editor. the editor is created within a html automatically by a library. imagine it like a tag within the html that creates the editor. therefore is the only way to style the editor is with a style tag within the html of the editor.

Comment: You can always insert style in the head of what you insert into the editor.  See this fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/DQfaab  The only hard part here is the CSS won't get saved with the content unless you save the entire HTML document.  You would have to have similar CSS / styles available in the content when you render it later outside the editor.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for me. Could you please provide an example in which the TinyMCE body is targeted and the background-color is changed to red with an <style></style> within the .html in which the TinyMCE is generated? Would highly appreciate.

Comment: The fiddle in my prior comment does exactly what you want ... did you try to run it?  What did you not understand about it?   http://fiddle.tinymce.com/DQfaab/1